# PdfBox encoding exception

Tags: java, pdfbox

U+20B9 ('.notdef') is not available in this font Helvetica encoding: WinAnsiEncoding

The above exception I got when I tried to print ₹ -123,456,789.00. I think that ₹ is not supported by Helvetica. And also some other symbols are also not supported. Could anyone please help to run my code without exception and output should contain the currency symbols.

Comment: use a font like this: `PDType0Font.load(document, new File("C:/windows/fonts/arial.ttf"));`

Answer (score 1):

You use *Helvetica* encoded with **WinAnsiEncoding**. That encoding does not contain a Rupee symbol, see ISO 32000, either part, Annex D. Thus, please use an encoding that includes the Rupee symbol.

Furthermore, you are likely to use *Helvetica* as one of the standard 14 fonts, the 14 fonts an ISO 32000-1 conforming PDF viewer has to provide by itself. In that case beware, viewers only need to provide the standard 14 fonts limited to the respective character sets from that Annex D, neither of which includes a Rupee symbol. Thus, please use a font program that includes the Rupee glyph.